# OneDrive API and Azure Active Directory setup to upload as personal account

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'll try to be as brief and comprehensive as I can.

**Objective:** To be able to upload PDF files generated after filling an HTML form to my personal OneDrive.

I have been looking into this for a few days now and cannot for the life of me figure out the proper way to set up the app and permissions in the Azure portal for this to work. I was initially using the `Personal Microsoft accounts only` option but quickly realized that would mean having to sign in. Then I tried the `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)` option. So this seemed to be a step in the right direction as the end-user does not need to do anything. I could use Application Permissions which would work without a signed-in user. That is basically what I want.

This lead to another issue, *Tenant does not have a SPO license*. After looking up more, it seems that to use the OneDrive APIs, you need to have a subscription. Like I mentioned, I am using a personal account (free).

I also tried daemon (since I can use application permissions and work without a user signed in). But based on the Microsoft Graph Get Files Permissions, Only Delegated permission is supported for personal Microsoft account.

I am trying to achieve this through PHP and using the libraries that are recommended everywhere. I honestly think that I am finding this much more complicated than it really is but I really can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

In conclusions, I can't answer these questions:

1. Can a personal free account (with student subscription or not) be used to access OneDrive?
2. If so, what supported account type is ideal for this?
3. And finally, is there anywhere I can follow to do this?

P.S. I have tried a lot more things I mentioned here, so in case anyone thinks of something I should have done, ask me and I'll update you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tried many and got many correct conclusions.

To make a personal account access the personal OneDrive, you have to use delegated permission. Application permission is not supported in this scene.

I know your requirement is not to sign in interactively. Unfortunately it's not supported to use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) for personal accounts.

[image]

So the only option is to use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). Both of them require you to sign in interactively.

In summary, uploading files to personal OneDrive using non-interactive login is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @AllenWu. I know this is not related directly, but is it possible to do with using Google Drive and their APIs? Or does it have the same restrictions?

Comment: @Saad Sorry I'm not familiar with non-Microsoft products:(. You can add a new post with related tags.