# Access Excel Online via a custom application in Node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

My app can access my Google Sheets via Google API and a service account without any problems. I try to do the same with Microsoft Excel On-Line.

I have a personal Microsoft account, one Excel file on OneDrive and admin access to Microsoft Azure. I can make queries with Microsoft Graph without any problems.

For my app, I went to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations. I created a new app, with clientId, tenantId, secret, etc.. Add the API permissions : User.ReadWrite.All, Files.Read.Write.All granted by admin only both types : Application and Delegated.

I wrote this code:

```
import {ConfidentialClientApplication} from '@azure/msal-node'
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'aed11b78-3498-4bc3-b7c9-e5d51cb1a79e',
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72119209-f1d8-4705-a507-8d1e76935c64",
        clientSecret: 'DqG7Q~ibnMrBmREhhCQppx5Q.HOlxZg39IpwK'
   }
};
var client = new ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

const request= {
        scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
}

let url1 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
let url2 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children'


let run = (async() => {
    let response = await client.acquireTokenByClientCredential(request)

    let query = await fetch(url1, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.accessToken
        }
    });
    
    let json  = await query.json()
    console.dir(json)

})()
```

(no worry I erased the credentials)

If I try the code with Url1 : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' , no problem I got my  users info.

> value: [
> {
> businessPhones: [],
> displayName: 'Pierre Roy',
> givenName: 'Pierre',
> jobTitle: null,
> mail: null,
> mobilePhone: null,
> officeLocation: null,
> preferredLanguage: 'en',
> surname: 'Roy',
> ...

However, if I try url2: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children'

No luck, I got this reply :

> {   error: {
> code: 'BadRequest',
> message: 'Tenant does not have a SPO license.',
> innerError: {
> date: '2021-10-22T02:01:58',
> 'request-id': '386808e2-13b0-458d-8131-e18653bfb1bd',
> 'client-request-id': '386808e2-13b0-458d-8131-e18653bfb1bd'
> }   } }

Which is I guess some SharePoint access issues.. I just want to make a personal app and access my personal on-line Excel files programmatically for testing purpose. SharePoint is for enterprises purposes and useless for my purpose.

Any solution for this ? Do I need to have SharePoint and pay some monthly fees to access my little online Excel file programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

> { error: { code: 'BadRequest', message: 'Tenant does not have a SPO
> license.', innerError: { date: '2021-10-22T02:01:58', 'request-id':
> '386808e2-13b0-458d-8131-e18653bfb1bd', 'client-request-id':
> '386808e2-13b0-458d-8131-e18653bfb1bd' } } }

Based on the error message, after referencing multiple [Stack Over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license) threads & [git hub](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1266) discussion understood that you can't use the Microsoft Graph API to access OneDrive without having SharePoint Business licenses.

if you are using a `personal account` in a registered `Azure Active Directory(AAD) app, that type isn't Personal Microsoft accounts only or Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)` you will get this error. Also, you need to use the correct endpoint to avoid errors.

The main problem is our account type. As a personal account, there are some restrictions to access one drive files. These restrictions are:

1. You can only use `Oauth2 Code Flow` or `Oauth2 Token Flow`. Both are interactive approaches. [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#supported-authentication-flows)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787193/onedrive-api-and-azure-active-directory-setup-to-upload-as-personal-account/66792238#66792238)
2. Your application registered in AAD needs be `Personal Microsoft accounts only or Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)` and each one have a different endpoint to acquire the access token (That you can saw clicking on `endpoint` button, near the delete app button in app page). [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license#comment80647746_46809518)
3. Enable these delegated permissions to your application registered in AAD: `Files.Read, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite, and Files.ReadWrite.All`.

Here is the reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733599/15968720) thread where user is trying to access the one Drive API using postman